# Converting microservices in the form of modules into a single jar

Tags: spring-boot, maven, microservices, multi-module

I have  a maven project which contains multiple modules. Each module is a microservice. I want to create a jar file out of the project which will combine all the microservices into one. How can this be done.

I tried the adding the below to the pom of the parent but it does not seem to be working

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <finalName>all-microservices</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>com.example.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: This is fundamentally wrong. How your different Microservices will be coming up. Each JAR would be working as independent JAR. Please provide more context as why you want to do it